# VBA passing cell reference into method parameter value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the Workbooks.OpenText method to open a text file in Excel using VBA and would like to pass the value in a cell, say B5, of the active workbook into the FieldInfo parameter. Specifically, I want to modify the following code:

```
Dim inputDir As String
Dim outputDir As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim inputDelim As String
Dim formatOptions As Variant

myFile = Range("B1").Value
inputDir = Range("B2").Value
outputDir = Range("B3").Value
inputDelim = Range("B4").Value
formatOptions = Range("B5").Value

        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=inputDir & myFile, StartRow:=1, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, _
            Other:=True, OtherChar:=inputDelim, _
            FieldInfo:=formatOptions
```

The value in B5 is

```
Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 2), _
Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1))
```

When you hardcode this value into formatOptions in the last line of the code above, everything works fine i.e...

```
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=inputDir & myFile, StartRow:=1, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, _
            Other:=True, OtherChar:=inputDelim, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 2), _
            Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1))
```

The problem I believe is that it is passing text surrounded by quotations. For the delimiter specification in the OtherChar parameter, if you hard code it, you include the quotes: "|" for example. But in the formatOptions parameter you don't put quotes around the Array code.

I know there may be better ways to pass the array of column types into Workbooks.OpenText but I think this issue will come up in other contexts and would like to understand why it is not working and what can be done so that instead of passing a string, it passes the Array as a object/code (the Set method did not work). I have searched for many hours for a solution and can't find one although I have a feeling the answer is very simple and I am not searching for the right words. I have seen similar questions throughout the web but nothing addressing this specifically. Apologies if I overlooked something.

Thank you in advance for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) `fieldInfo` input parameter is

> *an array  containing parse information for individual columns of data. The interpretation depends on the value of DataType. When the
>   data is delimited, this argument is an array of two-element arrays,
>   with each two-element array specifying the conversion options for a
>   particular column. The first element is the column number (1-based),
>   and the second element is one of the XlColumnDataType constants
>   specifying how the column is parsed.*

So, to be able to use it, you need to define an arrray of arrays of numbers:

```
1,2
2,2
3,1
...
```

I'd save this:

```
Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 2), _
Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1))
```

as:

```
1,2;2,2;3,1;4,2;5,1;6,1;7,1;8,1
```

then i'd try to split it via using function similar to:

```
Function GetFieldInfoFromCell(ByVal rCell As Range) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim fi As String, fis() As String
Dim fieldInfo() As Variant

fi = rCell
fis = Split(fi, ";")
ReDim Preserve fieldInfo(UBound(fis))

For i = LBound(fis) To UBound(fis)
    fieldInfo(i) = Array(Split(fis(i), ","))
Next

GetFieldInfoFromCell = fieldInfo

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim fieldInfo As Variant
'later
fieldInfo = GetFieldInfoFromCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B5"))
```

Note: Not tested!

Comment: And putting that in ONE cell would require some really horrible syntax, something like `{{1,2};{2,2};{3,2}}`. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah, just seen, good solution. :) Also, I doubt mine would ever work, I don't think Excel accepts arrays of arrayas in a single cell...

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the workaround! It works great. So it looks like the problem here was that an Array has to be created in VBA since it's not text.

Comment: `Split()` already return an array, so I'm not sure you need to wrap Split in `Array()` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yeah, `Split` return an array of string, but not an array of variant. As i mentioned in my answer, i do not tested it. Maybe, `Split` is enough and does not need to be dressed up in `Array()`. Cheers, Maciej